# Multiple Array name in one place

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I have a storage app where you input first name and surname separately and I was wondering if it was possible to put the names in the same tableView item.

Here is my tableView code:

```
#pragma mark UITableViewDataSource Methods

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tv dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    if ( nil == cell ) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }

    NSLog(@"indexPath.row = %d, patients.count = %d", indexPath.row, patients.count);
    Patient *thisPatient = [patients objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = thisPatient.patientName;
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    if (self.editing) {
        [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
    }
    return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
                        return [patients count];
}

#pragma mark UITableViewDelegate Methods

- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tv commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if ( editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete ) {
        [patients removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tv deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
    }
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tv didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    LSAppDelegate *delegate = (LSAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    PatientController *patient = [[PatientController alloc] initWithIndexPath:indexPath];
    [delegate.navController pushViewController:patient animated:YES];
    [tv deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

I tried `cell.textLabel.text = thisPatient.patientName, thisPatient.patientSurname;`

Though it only displays the first name, whereas it should display the first name and lastname 
Thanks in advance

Comment: where do you store this information? if you have a pool that can be accessed in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method, you just have to do so

Comment: I store the information in a database that is read when the file is loaded

Comment: you have several options to put the information in your cell. Depending on your requirements you can change the **style** of the cell and set the `detailedTextLabel`, or combine both in a simple string with `stringWithFormat` or `stringByAppandingFormat`

Comment: It is all done dynamically in an array @geo

Comment: I set the comment into an answer where it belongs to, now where the topic is reopened ;) please accept there :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to bring it from my comment to an anwser:

use

```
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", thisPatient.patientName, thisPatient.patientSurname];
```

or a custom format of your favor.

Also possible:

```
cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
```

-

```
cell.textLabel.text = thisPatient.patientName;
cell.detailTextLabel.text = thisPatient.patientSurname;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure it's possible. You need to make your own `UITableViewCell` though so you can display both fields into the same cell. Take a look at this [tutorial](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/customizing-uitableview-cell/), it does what you need.

Comment: I don't think it changes my answer. Use the tutorial to learn how to make your own custom cells.

Comment: I know how to make custom cells I just want to know how to add two items in an array to the same place

Comment: Make a new object, or use `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", thisPatient.firstName, thisPatient.patientlastName]`

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a custom cell with two separate labels. This has the advantage of placing the labels on top of each other or in any other arrangement. You can also use a framework such as the free [Sensible TableView](http://sensiblecocoa.com) to automatically fill in these labels for you.